# Variable drop down menu in php

Tags: php, mysql, menu

I want to have a dropdown menu with as many options as a number in my database.

This is what i have but doesnt work:

```
    <?php  

// set the pointer back to the beginning
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<div class="w-clearfix">
      <div class="price">' .$row['Price']. '€</div>

      //some code

          <select class="w-select selectorplatos" id="numeroplatos" name="numeroplatos" data-name="numeroplatos">';


    $capacity= "SELECT Capacity FROM Meals WHERE Meal_ID = '".$meal."';";
    $resultcap = mysqli_query($conn, $capacity) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysqli_error($conn));
    $i = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row1 = $resultcap->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'  .$i.  '">'  .$i.    "</option>";
       $i = $i+1;
    }

        echo   '</select>
          <input class="w-button pedirya" type="submit" value="¡Pedir ya!" data-wait="Espera por favor..." wait="Espera por favor...">
        </form>


        // more code here


mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Any clue whats wrong?
The command to display the drop down list cannot be executed.
Cheers!

Comment: provide your code and what you have already tried.

Comment: you do know that you have to wrap that code in <?php ?> ?

Comment: yes i just selected a part of it as its inside more php code

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
echo '<select class="w-select selectorplatos" id="numeroplatos" name="numeroplatos" data-name="numeroplatos">';

$capacity = "SELECT Capacity FROM Meals WHERE Meal_ID = '".$meal."';";
$resultcap = mysqli_query($conn, $capacity) or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysqli_error($connection));
$i = 1;

while($i < $resultcap) {
  echo '<option value="'  .$i.  '">'  .$i.   '</option>';
  $i = $i+1;
};
echo '</select>';
```

You weren't properly concatenating you MySQL query. It's also good practice to add `or die("Couldn't execute query. ". mysqli_error($connection))` to get feedback on what went wrong when executing your query.

I also added `echo` because, assuming all of this is wrapped inside `<?php ?>` tags, well you need to echo HTML.

Comment: edited using your query but returns "couldnt execute query", I think the problem is in the while ()

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. I have tested it:

```
    <select class="w-select selectorplatos" id="numeroplatos"  name="numeroplatos" data-name="numeroplatos">'
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT Capacity FROM meals";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $i = 1;
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option value="'  .$i.  '">'  .$i.    "</option>";
       $i = $i+1;
    }
   ?> 
   </select>
```

Comment: your connection to the db shoulde like this:                                         $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

Comment: doesnt work.. the thing is i have above it more php code that already uses fetch_assoc(), i edited the description so you can see

Comment: try to fetch all records:  $capacity= "SELECT Capacity FROM meals";

Answer (score 0):

Ok after a lot of research and inspiration from comments, i got it working the following way:

```
<?php
mysqli_data_seek($result, 0);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        echo '<div class="w-clearfix">
      <div class="price">' .$row['Price']. '€</div>
      <div class="priceindic">Precio por plato</div>
      <div class="w-form numplatosselect">
        <form class="w-clearfix" id="numerodeplatos" name="numerodeplatos" data-name="numerodeplatos" action="https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key='

          <label class="labelselector" for="numeroplatos-2">Numero de platos:</label>
          <select class="w-select selectorplatos" id="numeroplatos" name="numeroplatos" data-name="numeroplatos">';


    for ($i = 1; $i <= $row['Capacity']; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="' .$i.  '">' .$i. "</option>";
    }
   ?>
```

a simple for loop does the trick using fetch_assoc from above and including Capacity in the original query